# Send data to firebase using .set({})

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I read firebase documentation and found one example which should work for my purpose. I used .set({}) to send and change data of user's name but it doesn't' do anything in database. Do I do something wrong? Any help appreciated.

```
function userInfo(){
    var curUser = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + curUser).set({
        name: document.getElementById("name").value;
    });
}
```

At html part, I have button with id="save" and it allows user to enter information.

SOLVED:

```
var usersRef = firebase.database();
function userInfo(){
    var curUser = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    usersRef.ref('users/' + curUser).set({
        name: "name"
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the best way to solve this problem, but I rendered firebase.database() into a global variable in the same .js file and it worked for me.

Comment: Hey Lina. Great to hear that you find the solution. I'm not really sure what is different in the second snippet though. Can you explain? It would also be great if you could post that as an answer. Unlike on many sites, self-answers are encouraged on Stack Overflow. :-)